# Mouse click occurring in entire row width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I put a png logo on a row center. Row size is 1140px. I just need a clickable logo. But whenever i put my cursor on that row i found that entire row i mean 1140px width is clickable with a link. how to get rid of that.I just need a clickable logo image not entire row.

Here is my code:

```css
.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.image-logo {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a class="image-logo-click" href="#"><img class="image-logo" src="resources/contents/azuba.png" alt="azuba logo"></a>
</div>
```

[here is my website snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc3NW.jpg)

Comment: remove display:block and change it to display: inline-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use inline-block on the logo, blocks will take 100% width while inline-block will take up just what's needed

```css
.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto ;
}

.image-logo {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 20%;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a class="image-logo-click" href="#">
  <img class="image-logo" src="resources/contents/azuba.png" alt="abc def"></a>
</div>
```